# Web Deployment Project & TeamCity

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, teamcity, web-deployment-project

I am trying to build a web deployment project 2010 project for a solution. I have installed the Windows SDK and Web Deployment Project 2010 RTW on the build server, as well as copied over the missing `.target` files for MSBuild.

When attempting to build the project it spits out the following error

> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(1589, 9): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\aspnet_merge.exe" is invalid.

Unfortunately, searching around Google for results about this error don't reveal anything of much value. Any help to get TeamCity successfully building the web deployment project would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More suitable solution should be to set `TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin` property in your .wdproj file. For example:

```
<TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin>C:\Programmi\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\</TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin>
```

this setting, used in .dtproj file, override the default setting defined in Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets as you can see here

```
<Target
  Name="GetAspNetMergePath"
  DependsOnTargets="$(GetAspNetMergePathDependsOn)">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <AspnetMergeName>aspnet_merge.exe</AspnetMergeName>
      <AspnetMergePath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0</AspnetMergePath>
      <AspnetMergePath Condition="Exists('$(TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin)$(AspnetMergeName)')">$(TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin)</AspnetMergePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

the second `AspnetMergePath` means that if exists somewhere else a `$(TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin)` that point to an existing aspnet_merge.exe file, this will be used.

Answer (score 4):

ok your aspnet_merge is being pointed to the wrong place - in my build script i have something that ends up as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ASPNETPath Include="F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="ASPNET Merge">
    <AspNetMerge
      ExePath="@(ASPNETPath)"
      ApplicationPath=".\Release"
      SingleAssemblyName="CoreMicrosite"
      />
</Target>
```

try it and see

Comment: Cool, I set the `ExePath` for `aspnet_merge.exe` in the `NETFX 4.0 Tools` directory in the `Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets` and it's building correctly now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the following node at line 1562 in the file "Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets" :

```
    <Target
        Name="GetAspNetMergePath"
        DependsOnTargets="$(GetAspNetMergePathDependsOn)">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <AspnetMergeName>aspnet_merge.exe</AspnetMergeName>
            <!-- OLD
            <AspnetMergePath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0</AspnetMergePath>
            <AspnetMergePath Condition="Exists('$(TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin)$(AspnetMergeName)')">$(TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin)</AspnetMergePath>
            -->
            <AspnetMergePath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\</AspnetMergePath>
            <AspnetMergePath Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.0' ">C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\</AspnetMergePath>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
```

I added a workaround comment on the appropriate Microsoft Connect page :
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/706047/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment

Comment: +1 as the other answers assume aspnet_merge.exe is in the same location on dev machines and the build server. This fixes the problem but note that the latest SDK is 7.1, not 7.0A.