# teamcity fails to build because it misses Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets

Tags: c#, asp.net, teamcity

I get compilation error when try to build:

> d:\Co\RnD\Server\WebSites\Writers\Dev-Accounts-3.10\Accounts\BrandToolbar.Account\BrandToolbar.Account.csproj(3682, 5): error MSB4062: The "BrandToolbar.Web.Compression.MSBuild.CodeFilesTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly BrandToolbar.Web.Compression.MSBuild, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1570d3d1a3231508. Could not load file or assembly 'BrandToolbar.Web.Compression.MSBuild, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1570d3d1a3231508' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
>
> d:\Co\RnD\Server\WebSites\Writers\Dev-Accounts-3.10\Deployment\Account\Account.wdproj(73, 3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

However I couldn't find a place to download and insatll `Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets`

Comment: Have you installed Visual Studio or Windows SDK on the build server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this article about setting it up with teamcity, 
[Web Deployment Project & TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611370/web-deployment-project-teamcity)

you can download the MS web deployment stuff here, but from the article it looks like you need to copy the targets file from your VS machine

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24509